# How To Resolve MVVM Light NuGet Silverlight 5 Conflict With Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation DLL

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light, nuget, caliburn.micro

We have a Silverlight 5 project and we currently have a folder of shared library DLL's. We are in the process of changing to use NuGet for these libraries wherever possible.

One of the NuGet packages we want to use is MVVMLight, to replace the MVVM Light SL4 DLL's we are currently using, which were never upgraded when we moved from SL4 to SL5.

However, when we installed the NuGet package containing the SL5 DLL's it automatically changed our existing references to the Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation DLL file to one which came with the MVVM Light package, which has the same version number, but a different public key.

This has caused a conflict with some of our other code which is using the Prism library, which uses the Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation DLL, but, signed with the original public key.

Obviously we cannot use the same named DLL twice in the same folder, so, any suggestion on how to  resolve this issue, whilst keeping both Prism and MVVM Light packages installed from NuGet.

Thanks very much,

Martyn.

Comment: Since getting the answer below from @Filmindji, I've realised that I said the conflict was with Caliburn.Micro, which it is not, it is a conflict between MVVMLight and the Microsoft Prism library, over the version of Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation DLL, which could be solved, by an MVVMLight package which was dependent on the CommonServiceLocator package.

Comment: I had the same issue and posted it here as well.  I have since ripped out all the nuget packages from my solution for the time being. I am not sure I understand whey Laurent is using a differently signed ServiceLocation.DLL but I have gone back to keeping all used references on my PC for now until I feel I can trust nuget/MVVMLight again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem with Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll. In my case, this could be resolve if the nuget package of MvvmLight was dependent of [CommonServiceLocator](http://nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator) as I suggested here : http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/discussions/429311

So far, no news about that.

Edit : Laurent just push a version of MVVM Light using the CommonServiceLocator from Nuget.

Comment: Received a reply from Laurent Bugnion on the MVVM Light Codeplex forum, saying he is investigating how to achieve this and provide the necessary packages where applicable. See [link](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/discussions/429311).

Answer (score 0):

The Portable.CommonServiceLocator NuGet package contains the existing signed CSL binaries as well as the PCL one that supports windows 8, .net 4.5 and others. Still waiting on Microsoft to include the PCL in their official package, but the binaries are the same in the one I mentioned.

You can also try using Portable.MvvmLightLibs, which is a PCL version. That one supports all of the frameworks (WP7.5+, .NET 4.5, Store, SL4+) and uses the official Microsoft-signed CSL libraries.